# HTML Styling with Google API - Text-indent

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a chrome extension which creates MLA citations and uploads them to google drive. It works fine, and the styling works too. However, the text-indent property is ignored. I am sending the file using google's drive API. I need to know how to be able to use that property, so it looks like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam erat 
    velit, lobortis quis ipsum non, dapibus tincidunt dolor. Integer 
    commodo, metus ac commodo scelerisque, est erat faucibus neque, vel 
    commodo odio sapien ac nisl. Cras scelerisque mi id venenatis 
    fringilla.
```

The html sent:

```
html += '<p dir="ltr" style="line-height:2.0;margin-top:0pt;margin-
bottom:0pt;padding:0pt 0pt 0pt 36pt;text-indent: -36pt;"><span 
style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: &quot;Times New Roman&quot;; 
vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap;">' + text + '</span></p>';
```

Other Data

- convert: true
- uploadType: multipart
- GData-Version: 3.0
- mimeType: text/html

Extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ezcite/hglaojinolkdpdnnnhlohffjpckcodjh

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to solve this: Instead of exporting with the style attribute, I put the css into a style element, and just referenced the proper classes for the body.